# List 3 bootstrap cards per row using template loop

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, django-templates, jinja2

I'd like to list the cards as down below:

[image]

This is the code so far. My cards are listed one by one vertically. How can I achieve this?

```
{% extends 'base_content.html' %}
{% block content %}
{% for item in CATEGORY_CHOICES %}
<div class="row" style="justify-content: center;">
<div class="col-sm-3">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">{{ item.1 }}</h5>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The loop currently creates a new `row` for each item, which is why every card is stacking. It should only loop `col`, not `row`.
2. `col-sm-3` means "use 3/12 space per column at `sm` and above" which means **4 columns** (not 3) at the `sm` breakpoint and above. Use `col-sm-4` to display 3 cards per row at `sm` and above, or just `col-4` if you want 3 cards per row at all times.

```html
{% extends 'base_content.html' %}
{% block content %}

<!-- don't loop here -->
<div class="row justify-content-center">

  <!-- only loop the columns -->
  {% for item in CATEGORY_CHOICES %}
  <div class="col-sm-4"> <!-- not "col-sm-3" -->
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">{{ item.1 }}</h5>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  {% endfor %}

</div>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Also good practice would be switching to flex instead of grid system